# Discord.py on_message wont stop from sending the same message

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot where its supposed to send a message when some user say something without a prefix. E.g like "test", when one user say test in the channel, the bot should respond with "testing", its worked, but the problem is, the bot wont stop from sending "testing" even if the user already stop sending "test". Heres the code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'test' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('testing')
```

Comment: For future, `'test`' is inside `'testing'`, which is causing the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bot is seeing its own message.

Add a guard against that; if the message's author is the bot user itself, don't act on it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if 'test' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('testing')
```